# Bot is crawling urls that do not exist in my site. How to identify and fix them?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

When I look at access.log in my site, I find these entries in the file. These files are not generated by me and not sure where is bingbot finding them. Is this some spam sitemap.xml? I was trying to find the sitemaps but could not locate any which had these entries

```
ipaddress - - [19/Nov/2023:00:18:18 +0000] "GET /contentscat/goods HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/116.0.1938.76 Safari/537.36" "52.167.144.191"
ipaddress - - [19/Nov/2023:00:19:55 +0000] "GET /tanka-vs/top.cgi HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/116.0.1938.76 Safari/537.36" "52.167.144.163"
ipaddress - - [19/Nov/2023:00:24:07 +0000] "GET /category/voice HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/116.0.1938.76 Safari/537.36" "40.77.167.54"
```

Questions

1. Do these files exist in my site? Or there was seme rogue process which created them? It is a wordpress site that has been hacked few times and I am doing cleanup now
2. Is some other site referring to these invalid links?

Comment: Is it coming from a single IP address or different?

Comment: We have many similar questions already, as linked to above, and many more can be viewed using Search results like the ones [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=non+existent+urls+is%3Aq).